# Insert data into MySQLi via PHP - WAMP server

Tags: php, android, mysql, mysqli, wamp

I have a wamp server setup. It works perfectly :)
I then entered phpMyAdmin and created a table. With an android app I have made, I would like to insert a record in my database. The android (java) code is correct, I'm 100% sure of that. When I create a record though, it doesn't work.

Since I don't know PHP very well at all I assume my mistake lies somewhere in Register.php

Here is the file:
Any insight into what my problem is would be fantastic!

*Please note that I am using my correct public ip in the true file. I just entered a random one for the code below. Also, I have created a user with permissions required (in the place of username and password). The database "database" also DOES exist.*

**Register.php**

```
$con = mysqli_connect("http://148.12.0.153:3306","username","password", "database");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$balance = $_POST["balance"];
$NameAndSurname = $_POST["NameAndSurname"];
$DateOfBirth = $_POST["DateOfBirth"];
$SchoolName = $_POST["SchoolName"];
$Gender = $_POST["Gender"];
$Grade = $_POST["Grade"];
$Class = $_POST["Class"];
$Country = $_POST["Country"];
$Province = $_POST["Province"];
$Address = $_POST["Address"];
$City = $_POST["City"];
$PostalCode = $_POST["PostalCode"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, phone, balance, NameAndSurname, DateOfBirth, SchoolName, Gender, Grade, Class, Country, Province, Address, City, PostalCode) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssssisssiisssssi", $username, $email, $password, $phone, $balance, $NameAndSurname, $DateOfBirth, $SchoolName, $Gender, $Grade, $Class, $Country, $Province, $Address, $City, $PostalCode);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: I dont think port no 3306 is necessary. can u remove that and try again?

Comment: echo/print/log the contents of $statement, add this and the table ddl to the post

Comment: First of all try to remove http:// from the host and just try ip without http:// and try to print mysqli error by using echo mysqli_error($con);

Comment: the only thing I can see that might be the problem ( other than the previously mentioned port appended to the server address which should just be an ip address or hostname - no http, no port ) is that the field names are not encased with backticks and password appears to have special significane in mysql

Comment: The error recieved is 
Access denied for user 'mingan'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
That user has 'all privileges' though? I'm not sure what's wrong..

Comment: Just remove http:// and port no and i think it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok a number of things to mention here.

First you are using the android app to launch this `Register.php` script on your Apache server, just like it was a web page, so this script is running on the server and not your phone or tablet. Therefore Apache and MySQL and the script are all running on the WAMPServer PC. So your connection string does not need some real ip address, it can use and should use something like `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Next your database access code is assuming everything will just happen correctly and this may not be the case see above paragraph. So always check status codes and report back the status's to the calling program so it can make sensible decisions about what to do next. Its also a good idea to log errors to the PHP Error log, so when this goes live you can check logs and see if anything is going wrong without needing to run the phone app.

So try these changes :

```
// init the reply class
$result = new stdClass();
$result->status = 'OK';  


$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","username","password", "database");
if ( ! $con ) {
    $result->status        = 'ERROR';
    $result->error_code    = mysqli_connect_errno();
    $result->error_message = mysqli_connect_error();
    // terminate and report to error log
    error_log('Database connection failed'.mysqli_connect_error(), 0);
    echo json_encode($result);  // return status as json
    exit;
}

// You should never use data sent from the screen without
// validating it and cleaning it up so you need some sort of 
// $_POST = validate_sanity($_POST);

$username       = $_POST["username"];
$email          = $_POST["email"];
$password       = $_POST["password"];
$phone          = $_POST["phone"];
$balance        = $_POST["balance"];
$NameAndSurname = $_POST["NameAndSurname"];
$DateOfBirth    = $_POST["DateOfBirth"];
$SchoolName     = $_POST["SchoolName"];
$Gender         = $_POST["Gender"];
$Grade          = $_POST["Grade"];
$Class          = $_POST["Class"];
$Country        = $_POST["Country"];
$Province       = $_POST["Province"];
$Address        = $_POST["Address"];
$City           = $_POST["City"];
$PostalCode     = $_POST["PostalCode"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO users 
           (username, email, password, phone, 
            balance, NameAndSurname, DateOfBirth, 
            SchoolName, Gender, Grade, Class, 
            Country, Province, Address, City, 
            PostalCode) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql );
if ( ! $statement ) {
    $result->status        = 'ERROR';
    $result->error_code    = mysqli_errno();
    $result->error_message = mysqli_error();
    // terminate and report to error log
    error_log('Database connection failed'.mysqli_error(), 0);
    echo json_encode($result);  // return status as json
    exit;
}

$res = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssssisssiisssssi",
               $username, $email, $password, $phone, $balance, 
               $NameAndSurname, $DateOfBirth, $SchoolName, $Gender, 
               $Grade, $Class, $Country, $Province, $Address, $City, 
               $PostalCode);

if ( ! $res ) {
    $result->status        = 'ERROR';
    $result->error_code    = mysqli_errno();
    $result->error_message = mysqli_error();
    // terminate and report to error log
    error_log('Database connection failed'.mysqli_error(), 0);
    echo json_encode($result);  // return status as json
    exit;
}

if ( mysqli_stmt_execute($statement) ) {
    $result->status        = 'OK';
    $result->message       = 'Row deleted';
    echo json_encode($result);  // return status as json
    exit;
} else {
    $result->status        = 'ERROR';
    $result->error_code    = mysqli_errno();
    $result->error_message = mysqli_error();
    // terminate and report to error log
    error_log('Database DELETE failed'.mysqli_error(), 0);
    echo json_encode($result);  // return status as json
    exit;
}

//mysqli_close($con);
//PHP will do all the connection and statment closing automatically 
// So you dont actually need to do any of this unless you are running 
// a script the will consume large numbers of statement and you may
// feel it necessary to close them out to kepp the memory footprint smaller
```

Comment: What do you mean it works it was just supposed to identify the errors. Whatever I suppose I fixed something without realising it

Answer (score 0):

Change the mysqli_stmt_close to

```
mysqli_stmt_close($statement) or die(mysqli_error());
```

This will give you a more precise error as to why this is failing.